# Renew a pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, new-operator

Is it a thing not do to, or is it right? The fact is to use new many times on one pointer:

```
 double * a;
 a=new double (5);
 cout<<*a<<endl;

 a=new double(10);
 cout<<*a;
 delete a;
```

Thanks.

SOLUTION:
So one possible solution is?!

```
 double * a;
 a=new double (5);
 cout<<*a<<endl;
 delete a;
 a=new double(10);
 cout<<*a;
 delete a;
```

In case we don't know if the pointer `a` point to empty cell, it's possible to use NULL pointer:

```
 double * a=0;

 //... the code use *a to allocate or not some informations

 delete a;

 // ... the code continues with the possibility of allocate again using *a.
```

Comment: You're gonna leak the first one.

Comment: You'll leak something *every* time you do this. If you must have a pointer, use a smart pointer and its `reset` function.

Comment: @chris: The point of a *smart* pointer is that it does the resetting business automatically...

Comment: So if I don't want to leak, have I to do `delete` before the new `new`? In that case there's a way to know if the pointer doesn't allocate anything (point only to void memory)?

Comment: @TommasoFerrari, Again solved with a smart pointer and `if (p)`.

Comment: @KerrekSB, Never mind, you need a new pointer anyway. My bad.

Comment: @chris: Well, depending how you use it and how you call your member functions... I guess ` p.reset(new T)` works. I was thinking of `p = new T`.

Comment: @KerrekSB, I agree, an assignment would be more logical to read imo. For whatever reason, I thought `xxx_ptr<T>` had a `reset(T t)` function, which would just make it `p.reset({});` with your generic example, or `p.reset(5)` in another, whereas an assignment only taking a pointer would need more work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In answer to your follow up question, (how do you make sure you're not deleting a null pointer): It doesn't matter.  `delete null` does nothing.

It's better to write your code in a way that you know the state at any point: only assign pointers once.  If you really want to use the idiom in your question, use a smart pointer (which will do the deletion for you as it gets reset or goes out of scope):

```
std::auto_ptr a;
a.reset(new double(5));
cout << *a << endl;

a.reset(new double(10));
cout << *a << endl;

// no need to call delete at all.  std::auto_ptrs destructor will do it for you.
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not okay - the first allocated memory will leak. But the main reason is that it's not idiomatic C++. What's wrong with plain old

```
double a;
a = 5;
cout << a << endl;

a = 10;
cout << a;
```

Answer (score 2):

No, that will cause a memory leak. **Every** `new` needs a corresponding `delete`.

Answer (score 2):

It is OK. Because a pointer can point to what it wants. So a `double* p` can point to any objects with type `double`.

However, in your specific situation, it is not perfectly OK, because you have `new`ed a block of memory and then let the pointer change its target. The old `5` memory block has no pointer pointed to and you cannot access it anymore; however it still occupy a block of memory. This is considered as **memory leak**.

In this case, you may want to use something like

```
std::shared_ptr<double> p(new(10.0));
```

and then you can renew it to

```
p.reset(new(5.0));
```

Comment: Prefer `std::make_shared` to `new`.

Answer (score 1):

Before you do `a=new double(10);` you need to `delete a;` first. Otherwise, you'll end up with a small memory leak, seeing as you requested the memory and then never freed it. Your code should look like this:

```
double *a = new double(5);
cout << *a << endl;
delete a; // note the delete

a = new double(10);
cout << *a;
delete a;
```